# Why does WriteLine skip Tab when the number is integer instead of decimal or double

Tags: c#

This seems to be a strange behavior.

I have this code below that's pulling the values from database and then writing them to a file.

x.Amount is a property of type double.

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
foreach (var x in result)
{
                  sw.WriteLine("name:" + "\t" + 4 + "\t" + x.Amount + "\t" + x.age);

}
```

The issue is when the amount is integer or a whole number the tab doesn't get printed.

So I get.

```
name:   4    350.5    26
name:   4    350.25   29
name:   4    2000.25  29
name:   4    350 29
```

As you can see above, when the amount is a whole number the tab seems to be missing from the file.

I'm writing it to a file using code below.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Response.OutputStream, Encoding.Default))
            {
                writer.Write(sw.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: It's not missing.  It's going to the next tab stop.  Your amount should be written using some padding.

Comment: ok. How do I fix this? I want all of them to line up nicely like it does when there is a decimal in number. Can I convert whole number to say 35 to 35.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your tab is not missing; your editor is simply choosing that tab-stop.

To align your text into columns, specify a width for the columns. Here, I'll pad your amounts to 8 characters. Change this number as needed.

I present two solutions.  I recommend the first.

#### Solution 1: Using [Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.8)

Use [Composite Formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting?view=netframework-4.8) to pad the amount out to 8 characters:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
foreach (var x in result)
{
    sw.WriteLine(String.Format("name:\t{0}\t{1,-8}\t{2}", 4, x.Amount, x.age));
}
```

#### Solution 2: Concatenation

While I recommend using Composite Formatting, you can do this without:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
foreach (var x in result)
{
    sw.WriteLine("name:" + "\t" + 4 + "\t" + x.Amount.ToString().PadRight(8) + "\t" + x.age);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The tab is not missing. Think of tabs as tables with columns. Each column start is a tab stop location. Does not matter how many letters are in column1, the next column2 will always start from the left edge. So the values in column 1 and column2 will have reduced spacing between them. It will look like the spacing is wrong, but it actually changed columns, it just appears that it is wrong.

a       |b       |c

aaaa    |bbbb    |c